# I want to transform a xml file into RDF file with XSLT but the xml file looks a little bizarre to me

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to know how to transform a xml file like this:

```
<doc>
   <str name="uri">A URI</str>                      
   <str name="name">test</str>
   <str name="vivo-url">A url</str>
</doc>
```

Into a xml file like this:

```
<doc>
  <uri>A uri</uri>                      
  <name>test</name>
  <vivo-url>A url</vivo-url>
</doc>
```

Comment: To get the best answer you should provide some code that you have attempted to use to get your desired result.

Comment: Where's the bizarre part?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        <doc>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./str"/>
        </doc>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="str">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

This adds line-breaks with xsl:text (a bit ugly).

The **xsl:element** creates an XML element with tag name the `name` attribute of `str`.

Comment: "*This adds line-breaks with xsl:text*" Does it? What happens when you remove the xsl:text elements?

Comment: @michael.hor257k then the whitespace of the template is emitted. Using "correct" whitespace in the templates makes them no longer structured for reading. I think you meant that. Though how to formulate this side-issue without sounding over-punctillious?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. The xsl:text elements in your stylesheet are not doing anything. The `indent` attribute of the xsl:output element does.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks, though I seem to have used a different XML parser than you with reversed effects. A new java 8 install.